# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" on R to install statmod package

Tags: r, compiler-errors, package, gfortran, statmodels

I'm new on **R** version **3.6.3** (2020-02-29). I'm working on a Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia. I tried to install the package **statmod** with this code line:

`install.package("statmod")`

When I compiled this line R return this error:

**error**:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o statmod.so gaussq2.o init.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'statmod.so' failed
make: *** [statmod.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘statmod’
* removing ‘/home/etudiant/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/statmod’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘statmod’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp8yGctp/downloaded_packages’
```

More informations:

`gfortran` compile basic function and when I wrote `gfortran -v` in my terminal, I got this answer :

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
```

I don't know how to solve this error. If someone has an idea that can really help me.
Thank you very much by advance.

Comment: Do you have gfortran installed? If yes, where? Where is your libgfortran.so? If you use "LANG="C"" before a command in Linux, you will get the error messages in English and not in French.

Comment: I have gfortran in /usr/bin. For libgfortran.so I have multiple version most of them are in /home/etudiant/anaconda3/lib or for libfortran.so.4 it's in /usr/local/julia/lib/julia

Comment: Is any of those directories containing the `libgfortran.so` in your LIBRARY_PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Does you gfortran (that one that runs when you just write `gfortran` if you have multiple ones) compile basic programs (note that the most basic program is just a sole `end` in some `test.f90` file)?

Comment: I don't find LIBRARY_PATH, I search how to access to it but don't know how. Also I don't know how to compile anything with gfortran.

Comment: You probably have some mess in your gcc and gfortran installations. What does `gcc -v` say? Is it the same version from the same location as your `gfortran`?

Comment: For `gcc -v` I have the version 9.4.0 but for `gfortran -v` I have the version 7.5.0. Maybe should I uninstall gfortran (all the version) and install again?

Comment: You should have the whole GCC (GNU compiler collection) installed as a single piece installed together. There are various ways how to have multiple versions on a single computer at the same time. We cannot discuss the details here. It requires some basic sysadmin knowledge.